# Quarkus: SRCFG00019: Failed to create new instance from Converter constructor

Tags: macos, redis, quarkus

I am new to this framework and I'm following this guide to setup a DB(redis) with Quarkus
https://quarkus.io/guides/redis

However after setting up redis and following the guide, I get the following error when I run

```
mvn quarkus:dev
```

---

```
2021-04-28 01:31:29,418 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (vert.x-worker-thread-4) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.dev.appstate.ApplicationStateNotification.waitForApplicationStart(ApplicationStateNotification.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.runMainClass(StartupActionImpl.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.restartApp(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:191)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.restartCallback(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:175)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.doScan(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:254)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$2.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$2.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:52)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:807)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:90)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:100)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:42)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:119)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(GeneratedMain.zig:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$3.run(StartupActionImpl.java:134)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: One or more configuration errors have prevented the application from starting. The errors are:
  - SRCFG00019: Failed to create new instance from Converter constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the redis properties I set in **application.properties** had a space at the end

```
quarkus.redis.hosts=redis://localhost:6379
```

I found this by accident as I didn't have many properties, I wish quarkus provided a better stacktrace.